Android/Kotlin - Android TV Remote Control
I’m currently working on an Android Remote Control application. I have successfully connected to the TV and sent simple commands with keycodes to control the TV.
However, I’m still stuck on the voice assistant and text input features:

For the voice assistant, I have already sent a command with the KEYCODE_SEARCH keycode to invoke the assistant. As far as I know, I need to work with the functions RemoteVoicePayload, RemoteVoiceBegin, and RemoteVoiceEnd. However, I can’t clearly understand the logic—what to call first and what values to put in.
For the keyboard text input, I sent commands with keycode_$char with short direction, but it only accepts number keycodes (1-9) in the text field. I don’t know what I’m missing, and I still don’t know how to handle shifted characters (A-Z).

I spent a few days researching this topic but haven’t found many documents, examples, or projects about it. Have you guys worked on this before? How can I handle these features, or do you have any keywords I can research?
Thank you, guys.
Some keywords I can research, or some explanting what I'm missing, or maybe just the logic I can working on

update on my case, after I call RemoteVoiceBegin with VoiceConfig, I received a message like this then socket close, logReceivedMessage: remote_error {
value: true
message {
voice_begin {
session_id: -1
voice_config {
audio_format: 2
channel_config: 16
sample_rate: 8000}}}}
where did i do wrong, hmmm

hi, did you managed to get any progress?
